# Hibernate exception on insertion after trigger fired

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

on postgresql, we use hibernate and trigger to move row on history table when we met some condition. On update, all is OK : after saving an updated entity, the row is moved in history table. But on some case, the moving condition is met at insertion. So I created a trigger that be fired before insertion, and insert nothing. In psql, all is ok. But when saving entity

```
UpBox upBox1 = upRepository.saveAndFlush(upBox);
```

I get this exception :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
```

Here my entity :

```
@Table(name = "up_box")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class UpBox implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // other attributes and getters / setters
}
```

My trigger ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION historyFromUpBoxInsertion( ) RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO history (
        device, payload, created, msg_date, 
        acked, frame_id, frame_type, link, direction
    ) VALUES (
        new.device, new.payload, new.processed, new.created,
        new.acked, new.frame_id, new.frame_type, new.link, 'UP'
    );
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER historyFromUpBoxInsertion_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON up_box
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.processed IS NOT NULL)
execute procedure historyFromUpBoxInsertion( );
```

If I use a after trigger and delete inserted row after copy in history table, all is OK, but I have two useless requests, insert and delete in up_box. Is it possible to use this before trigger on insertion with hibernate ?

Thanks, Denis

Comment: Just a tip: dont forget to evict the entity that trigger the copy/delete after the insert or your hibernate cache will not be synchronized

Comment: by returning updated value in trigger resolves this problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't return null in trigger, return NEW. It will work. At least working for me after modifying it.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer